# c# launch .exe from a remote folder

Tags: c#, networking

I made a .exe program in c# and locally works fine... but if I put the .exe into a remote path, when I launch, it gives error..
I use framework 2.0
how can I solve this?

thanks

edit:
this is the error:
[image]

and if I launch the program locally, it works fine ( I copied all the folder with directories...)

Comment: What error do you get? And if your project is dependent on other dlls, you need to copy them as well with the exe.

Comment: What is teh error , you are getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is "code access security"; a random network share has **very** little trust from the core engine by default.
With 2.0, your options are:

- use a ClickOnce instead (execute the `.application`, not the `.exe`)
- use [`caspol.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28VS.80%29.aspx) (on every client) to tell it to trust the share
- don't deploy that way (i.e. use an installer)

With some of the later service packs (it might be SP 2, I can't remember), *mapped shares* get more trust, i.e. `\\server\share` **won't** have enough trust by default, but `h:` (which is *mapped* to `\\server\share`) *will* run.

My preference would be the ClickOnce deployment since it works on all versions.

Comment: @ghiboz see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx. In Visual Studio this is the "publish" option; just set it to publish to a file location.

Answer (score 2):

If feasible, upgrade to .NET 3.5 SP1. This .NET Framework version will allow you to start executables off a network share:

> **[.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Allows managed code to be launched from a network share!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx)**

Comment: Interesting. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Cool; I even remembered the right version ;p (3.5-SP1 is bundled with 2.0-SP2)